# Run external CSS only in test mode in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a CSS file that I want to run only in test mode, and not in development or production. I know how to do this inline as follows:

```
<% if Rails.env.test? &>
  <style>
    //My test only styles
  </style>
<% end %>
```

This works, however, I prefer to avoid inline stylesheets since they're unorganized and hard to maintain. I've tried applying it to an external stylesheet as such:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'my_stylesheet.css' if Rails.env.test? %>
```

But this only works if I add my CSS file to applications.css. And If I do this, the file gets added regardless of which environment I'm running in.

So my question is, how I can add an external stylesheet in rails that is only run while in test mode? For bonus points, how could I get rails to compile SASS that only runs in test mode?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a perfect solution, but you could consider adding a class to the `html` or `body` tag in test mode and then explicitly specifying that class for your test styles.

This would give you the clean separation and maintainability benefits but the trade-off is that you would still need these to be compiled by the asset pipeline.